# Iterate over a list until the resulting list is an empty list

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I'm trying to see if I can do something like this:

Say I have a list: [1, 8, 90, 100, 82]

Now, what I would like to do is something like this

```
print [8, 90, 100, 82]
print [90, 100, 82]
print [100, 82]
print [82]
```

So basically, I would like to print the remainder of the list until I get an empty list, and then stop. Is there some way I can do this in Haskell?

EDIT: I'm looking for a more general solution. For example, I'd also like to be able to produce this:

list [10, 80, 90, 82, 28]

```
 [70, 80, 72, 18]
 [52, 62, 54]
 [10, 2]
 [8]
```

Comment: The "general solution" example looks like unrelated lists, and is confusing. Shouldn't those list be the tails of `[10,80,90,82,28]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about exploiting the IO monad:

```
func [_] = return ()
func (_:xs) = print xs >> func xs
```

When one calls this it results in:

```
*Main> func [1, 8, 90, 100, 82]
[8,90,100,82]
[90,100,82]
[100,82]
[82]
```

As you can read [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside), the `return` can be seen as the "no operation" operation and the binding operator`>>` can be seen as *perform the first operation before the second operation*.

Comment: This worked! If no one comments soon with a solution that does not require a function definition, I'll accept this.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `mapM_` function to apply `print` for each element in the list. There is function `tails`, returns all final segments of the argument (however, it also returns empty list as last element, so, you could combine it with `init` function). Finally, you could skip first element, if you do not want to print it, use function `tail`:

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print . init . tails $ tail [1, 8, 90, 100, 82]
```

Prints:

```
[8,90,100,82]
[90,100,82]
[100,82]
[82]
```

Of course, it is possible to solve your problem using separate functions. Note, that I add two more functions to make code more readable and reusable:

```
import Data.List

tailsExceptOriginalAndEmpty :: [a] -> [[a]]
tailsExceptOriginalAndEmpty = init . tails . tail

printListofLists :: (Show a) => [[a]] -> IO ()
printListofLists = mapM_ print

printTailsExceptOriginalAndEmpty :: (Show a) => [a] -> IO ()
printTailsExceptOriginalAndEmpty = printListofLists . tailsExceptOriginalAndEmpty

main :: IO ()
main = printTailsExceptOriginalAndEmpty [1, 8, 90, 100, 82]
```

Note also, that you should handle case with empty input list. In the current implementation it will raise an error.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I am looking for a more general solution, one that I could use a variety of functions for. I'll amend the original question

Comment: @ragesalmon Turning this into a function which takes a list parameter is trivial. E.g. `foo list = mapM_ print . init . tails $ tail list`.

Comment: @ragesalmon, sorry for late comment. Of course, it is possible to extract this code into separate functions. Please, take a look at the update.